# What url is generated for custom methods in Spring Data Rest repositories?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have a spring-data-rest repository with this method:

```
long countByName(String name);
```

What URL should I use to access this method from a client?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to add the `@Param` annotation:

```
long countByUuid(@Param("uuid") String uuid);
```

And then you can access this method with the following url:

```
/{repository}/search/countByUuid?uuid=test
```